# Html css get input values and save it in array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form in which I have multiple forms to like add and remove so it can be one or two or 3.

I just want to get data from the form and save it in an array

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <section>
         <div class="container">
            <form method="post" action="submit.php">
               <div class="form-group fieldGroup">
                  <div class="input-group">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                           <input type="text" name="userfname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                           <input type="text" name="usermname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Middle Name"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                           <input type="text" name="userlname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name"/>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                           <input type="text" name="usermobilenumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                           <input type="text" name="userdob" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Date of birth"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                           <select id="gender">
                              <option value="volvo">Male</option>
                              <option value="saab">Female</option>
                           </select>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                           <input type="text" name="useremail" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email id"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                           <input type="text" name="userpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="password"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                           <select id="User Category">
                              <option value="">Head of Family</option>
                              <option value="">Mother</option>
                              <option value="">Father</option>
                              <option value="">Brother</option>
                              <option value="">Sister</option>
                              <option value="">Dependent</option>
                              <option value="">Child</option>
                              <option value="">Spouse</option>
                           </select>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"> 
                           <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success addMore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add</a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT"/>
            </form>
            <!-- copy of input fields group -->
            <div class="form-group fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
               <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <input type="text" name="userfname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name"/>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <input type="text" name="usermname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Middle Name"/>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <input type="text" name="userlname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name"/>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <input type="text" name="usermobilenumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number"/>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <input type="text" name="userdob" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Date of birth"/>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <select id="gender">
                           <option value="volvo">Male</option>
                           <option value="saab">Female</option>
                        </select>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <input type="text" name="useremail" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email id"/>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <input type="text" name="userpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="password"/>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <select id="User Category" class="form-control">
                           <option value="">Head of Family</option>
                           <option value="">Mother</option>
                           <option value="">Father</option>
                           <option value="">Brother</option>
                           <option value="">Sister</option>
                           <option value="">Dependent</option>
                           <option value="">Child</option>
                           <option value="">Spouse</option>
                        </select>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group-addon"> 
                     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
      <script src="js/index.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //group add limit
    var maxGroup = 15;
    
    //add more fields group
    $(".addMore").click(function(){
        if($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < maxGroup){
            var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group fieldGroup">'+$(".fieldGroupCopy").html()+'</div>';
            $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
        }else{
            alert('Maximum '+maxGroup+' groups are allowed.');
        }
    });
    
    //remove fields group
    $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
        $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
    });
});
```

Now what I want to do is get values of form in array-like

```
[{'name': 'inputname', 'email': 'inputEmail'}, {'name': 'inputname', 'email': 'inputEmail'},]
```

As you can see I have 2 arrays in JSON that I want my data so how many forms will add it will increase data.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

try serialization, the method walks through the specified fields and collects data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).